# Class name hydration mismatch in server and client, (Warning: Prop `className` did not match Server and Client)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, right-to-left

I don't know my issue is a **bug** or just a **support** term or just a **configuration** mismach, but I spend much time, Not happy go lucky writing here to somebody settle my issue. no!

I searched for 3 days, Even just sleep about 10 hours in this 3 days, try many ways, even I use [Gitter](https://gitter.im/mui-org/material-ui) but no one answer me, I see issues [#10982](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10982) and [#11506](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11506) and many `Stack Overflow` question and answers but I couldn't fix my issue and didn't find right way.

Absolutely I read and read many times the `Material-UI` [Docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/) but I exactly did what the Docs said.

At last, I see class name hydration mismatch in server and client,  this warning:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "MuiFormLabel-root-134 MuiInputLabel-root-129 MuiInputLabel-formControl-130 MuiInputLabel-animated-133" Client: "MuiFormLabel-root-10 MuiInputLabel-root-5 MuiInputLabel-formControl-6 MuiInputLabel-animated-9"
```

I swear I tried many ways and searched a lot. I'm using `Material-UI` version `1.2.1`.

This is my `Index` component as a root component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import styles from 'StylesRoot/styles.pcss';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles['root-wrapper']}>
                <Helmet
                    htmlAttributes={{lang: 'fa', amp: undefined}}
                    bodyAttributes={{dir: 'rtl'}}
                    titleTemplate='اسکن - %s'
                    titleAttributes={{itemprop: 'name', lang: 'fa'}}
                    meta={[
                        {name: 'description', content: 'صفحه اتصال اعضاء'},
                        {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'},
                    ]}
                    link={[{rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/dist/styles.css'}]}
                />
                <TextField label='test' helperText='help'/>
            </div>
        );
    };
}
```

Here below you can see my `server.jsx` and `client.jsx`:

```
//--------------------------------------------client.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {hydrate} from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {lightBlue, red} from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import Index from './app/index';
import RTL from './app/public/rtl';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: lightBlue,
        accent: red,
        type: 'light',
    },
    direction: 'rtl',
});

class Main extends React.Component {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    componentDidMount() {
        const jssStyles = document.getElementById('jss-server-side');
        if (jssStyles && jssStyles.parentNode) {
            jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Index {...this.props}/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

hydrate((
    <RTL>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Main/>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </RTL>
), document.getElementById('root'));



//--------------------------------------------server.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';
import {SheetsRegistry} from 'react-jss/lib/jss';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
import {MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme, createGenerateClassName} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {red, lightBlue} from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import Template from './app/template';
import Index from './app/index';
import RTL from './app/public/rtl';

export default function serverRenderer({clientStats, serverStats}) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        const context = {};
        const sheetsRegistry = new SheetsRegistry();
        const theme = createMuiTheme({
            palette: {
                primary: lightBlue,
                accent: red,
                type: 'light',
            },
            direction: 'rtl',
        });
        const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();
        const markup = renderToString(
            <JssProvider registry={sheetsRegistry} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <RTL>
                    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} sheetsManager={new Map()}>
                        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                            <Index/>
                        </StaticRouter>
                    </MuiThemeProvider>
                </RTL>
            </JssProvider>
        );
        const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

        const jss = sheetsRegistry.toString();

        res.status(200).send(Template({
            markup: markup,
            helmet: helmet,
            jss: jss,
        }));
    };
}
```

So now it's needed to `template.jsx`:

```
export default ({ markup, helmet, jss }) => {
    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html ${helmet.htmlAttributes.toString()}>
                <head>
                    ${helmet.title.toString()}
                    ${helmet.meta.toString()}                   
                    ${helmet.link.toString()}
                    <style id='jss-server-side'>${jss}</style>                                  
                </head>
                <body ${helmet.bodyAttributes.toString()}>
                    <div id='root'>${markup}</div>
                    <script src='/dist/client.js' async></script>
                </body>
            </html>`;
};
```

Ok, Now it is possible that this question is asked *What is `RTL`?* and *Why you wrap `MuiThemeProvider` inside it in both server and client?*

So first see `RTL` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {create} from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import {createGenerateClassName, jssPreset} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const jss = create({plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()]});

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

export default props => (
    <JssProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
        {props.children}
    </JssProvider>
);
```

I saw it in `Material-UI` [Docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/) and I believe the documentation is a little poor and could be improved. I asked myself, *Why documentation pass a `props.children` for this function?* and I guess maybe this function should wrap something. so I try many shapes and it works. but in the first call in browser after build. when I refresh the browser then the warning appears  and I see this damn shape:

[image]

Surely I wanna see below shape, but I see it just once after build:

[image]

I don't know what is going wrong. I leave an issue on [`Github`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12203) too. And upload a [mini repo](https://gitlab.com/amerllica/varizHell) for this issue, for seeing my issue just `pull`, and run `npm install` then `num run dev`. the project is accessible on [localhost:4000](http://localhost:4000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this way is proper or not, But it works well, Actually, I find out, using separate `RTL` Component, is not a good way, This cause to the inconsistency between server and client, I use the [Right-to-Left](https://material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/) Documentation page for each server and client-side separately, Hence omit the `Rtl.jsx` file and it's component from my project, So, `server.jsx` and `client.jsx` is like below:

```
//---------------------------------------------client.jsx
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {hydrate} from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {
    MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme,
    createGenerateClassName, jssPreset
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {create} from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import {lightBlue, red} from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import Index from './app/index';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: lightBlue,
        accent: red,
        type: 'light',
    },
    direction: 'rtl',
});

const jssRTL = create({plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()]});

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

class Main extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const jssStyles = document.getElementById('jss-server-side');
        if (jssStyles) {
            jssStyles.remove();
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Index {...this.props}/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

hydrate((
    <JssProvider jss={jssRTL} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Main/>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </JssProvider>
), document.getElementById('root'));


//---------------------------------------------server.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';
import {SheetsRegistry} from 'react-jss/lib/jss';
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
import {
    MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme,
    createGenerateClassName, jssPreset
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {create} from 'jss';
import rtl from 'jss-rtl';
import {red, lightBlue} from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import Template from './app/template';
import Index from './app/index';

export default function serverRenderer({clientStats, serverStats}) {
    return (req, res, next) => {

        const context = {};

        const sheetsRegistry = new SheetsRegistry();

        const theme = createMuiTheme({
            palette: {
                primary: lightBlue,
                accent: red,
                type: 'light',
            },
            direction: 'rtl',
        });

        const jssRTL = create({plugins: [...jssPreset().plugins, rtl()]});

        const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();

        const markup = renderToString(
            <JssProvider jss={jssRTL}
                         registry={sheetsRegistry}
                         generateClassName={generateClassName}>
                <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme} sheetsManager={new Map()}>
                    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                        <Index pathname={req.url}/>
                    </StaticRouter>
                </MuiThemeProvider>
            </JssProvider>
        );
        const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();

        const jss = sheetsRegistry.toString();

        res.status(200).send(Template({
            markup,
            helmet,
            jss,
        }));
    };
}
```

It works well on both sides, server, and client and makes consistent `Material-UI` `CSS` in style tag.